# Как преобразовать список ArrayList<Byte> в массив byte[]?

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist, byte

Такой вариант знаю:

```java
ArrayList<Byte> list = new ArrayList<>();

byte[] bytes = new byte[list.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    bytes[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Есть какие-то более короткие и удобные варианты???

Comment: а как же `toArray()` ?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это же документацию читать надо!

Comment: этот описанный случай самый простой и удобный. Чтобы он был еще удобнее - надо вынести его в статический метод и использовать уже его

Comment: toArray() не работает при преобразовании в byte[] bytes. Только для Byte [] bytes. Но вопрос был именно про byte[] bytes!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Если почитать в документации , то можно найти вот таких 2 метода

```
public Object[] toArray();

public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

Можете использовать любой из них.

```
public class ArrayListExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(2);
         
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("D");
         
        //Convert to object array
        Object[] array = list.toArray();
         
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString(array) );
 
        //Iterate and convert to desired type
        for(Object o : array) {
            String s = (String) o;
             
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: toArray() не работает при преобразовании в byte[] bytes. Только для Byte [] bytes. Но вопрос был именно про byte[] bytes!!!!!!

Comment: Вы не можете создавать ArrayList<byte> т.к обощенным типом не может быть примитив. К тому же в Java есть автоупаковка и распаковка примитивом в их обертки. Или я не могу понять в чем ваш вопрос

Comment: преобразовать 
ArrayList<Byte>list = new ArrayList<>() в массив примитивов byte[] bytes????

Answer (score 0):

```java
ArrayList<Byte> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add((byte) 1);
list.add((byte) 2);
list.add((byte) 3);
```

---

#### Преобразовываем `ArrayList<Byte>` в массив

1. В массив `Byte[]` с помощью метода [`Collection.toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)):

   ```java
   Byte[] arr1 = list.toArray(Byte[]::new);

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1)); // [1, 2, 3]
   ```
2. В массив `byte[]` или `Byte[]` с помощью [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

   ```java
   byte[] arr2 = new byte[list.size()];

   IntStream.range(0, list.size()).forEach(i -> arr2[i] = list.get(i));

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [1, 2, 3]
   ```
3. В массив `byte[]` или `Byte[]` с помощью цикла `for`:

   ```java
   byte[] arr3 = new byte[list.size()];

   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
       arr3[i] = list.get(i);
   }

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3)); // [1, 2, 3]
   ```
4. В массив `Byte[]` с помощью метода [`Arrays.copyOf(U[],int,Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(U%5B%5D,%20int,%20java.lang.Class)):

   ```java
   Byte[] arr4 = Arrays.copyOf(list.toArray(), list.size(), Byte[].class);

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr4)); // [1, 2, 3]
   ```
5. В массив `Byte[]` с помощью метода [`System.arraycopy(Object,int,Object,int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)):

   ```java
   Byte[] arr5 = new Byte[list.size()];

   System.arraycopy(list.toArray(), 0, arr5, 0, list.size());

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr5)); // [1, 2, 3]
   ```
6. В массив `Byte[]` с помощью метода [`Arrays.setAll(T[],IntFunction))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-):

   ```java
   Byte[] arr6 = new Byte[list.size()];

   Arrays.setAll(arr6, list::get);

   System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr6)); // [1, 2, 3]
   ```

Comment: В массив примитивов `byte[]` - см. п2 п3.

Comment: Про п.3 я писал в начале, за п.2 спасибо!